# bundle exec rake db:populate - activerecord::recordinvalid:validation failed:email has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, railstutorial.org

I am currently at chapter 10 of michael hartl's tutorial and there is a problem when i try to do bundle exec rake db:populate.

Attached is the error message:

```
rake aborted!                                                                                                                        
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken                                                         
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'                      
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'                       
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_st
atus'                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `bl
ock in transaction'                                                                                                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `wi
thin_new_transaction'                                                                                                                
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `tr
ansaction'                                                                                                                           
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'    
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'                                
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:41:in `create!'                                
/home/action/workspace/app3/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'                                   
Tasks: TOP => db:populate                                                                                                            
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Attached is the sample_data.rake file:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    admin = User.create!(name: "Example User",
                         email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                         password: "foobar",
                         password_confirmation: "foobar",
                         admin: true)
    User.create!(name: "Example User",
                 email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                 password: "foobar",
                 password_confirmation: "foobar")
    99.times do |n|
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password  = "password"
      User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
      users = User.all(limit: 6)
      50.times do
        content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
        users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You're trying to create two users with the email example@railstutorial.org and have validation on the user model.  Just remove one of them from the rake file.

Comment: @Baloo by rake file do u mean sample_data.rake? or Rakefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
admin = User.create!(name: "Example User",
  email: "example@railstutorial.org",
  password: "foobar",
  password_confirmation: "foobar",
  admin: true)

User.create!(name: "Example User",
  email: "example@railstutorial.org", # This email is used to create admin above.
                                      # Use another email here
  password: "foobar",
  password_confirmation: "foobar")
```

The error is from this line

```
users = User.all(limit: 6)
```

The active record method `all` doesnt accept any parameters. Change it to

```
users = User.limit(6)
```

Comment: Hi i did that and i got argument error: wrong number of arugments (1 for 0)

Comment: From which line, and what is the code in that line. The error message means, you are calling a method with 1 argument, but it doesnt expect any.

Comment: This is the error!

rake aborted!                                                                                                                        
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)                                                                                   
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:24:in `all'                                  
/home/action/workspace/app3/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'                /action/workspace/app3/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:14:in `times'

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have solved the problem, I encountered this as well and solved it by adding `attr_accessible :content` or other `attr_accessible` in the model files. I hope this would help someone else.